# Tortoisehg keyring extension configuration

Tags: keyrings, mercurial

I have tortoisehg (2.1.1) installed on Ubuntu 10.10 and it is working correctly. I would like to configure the [keyring extension](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/2.0/extensions.html#mercurial-keyring) but am having trouble finding the mercurial.ini file on my system as stated in the directions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Mercurial system uses a set of configuration files to control aspects of its behaviour.

- (Unix) /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc, (Unix) /etc/mercurial/hgrc

> Per-installation configuration files, searched for in the directory
>   where Mercurial is installed.  is the parent directory
>   of the hg executable (or symlink) being run. For example, if installed
>   in /shared/tools/bin/hg, Mercurial will look in
>   /shared/tools/etc/mercurial/hgrc. Options in these files apply to all
>   Mercurial commands executed by any user in any directory.

- (Unix) /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc, (Unix) /etc/mercurial/hgrc

> Per-system configuration files, for the system on which Mercurial is
>   running. Options in these files apply to all Mercurial commands
>   executed by any user in any directory. Options in these files override
>   per-installation options.

- (Unix) $HOME/.hgrc

> Per-user configuration file(s), for the user running Mercurial. On
>   Windows 9x, %HOME% is replaced by %APPDATA%. Options in these files
>   apply to all Mercurial commands executed by this user in any
>   directory. Options in thes files override per-installation and
>   per-system options.